# How many apps can I run off a Windows instance on Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, web-applications, google-compute-engine

I am new to Compute Engine and I am seeking some clarification with regards to Windows instance. If I create one Windows instance and I use this instance to run say, an nopCommerce site using domain_A.com, can I also use the same instance to run say a Wordpress site under domain_B.com? Can one Windows instance run multiple apps or do I need 2 separate Windows instances in above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are hosting your applications. Consider you have an App1 and App2 and you are hosting both of your apps in a single instance using a particular Web Server say Tomcat or JBoss.

Now, if you want to host App1 and App2 on the same instance, you need to ensure that you run two separate instances of your Web Server (Tomcat or JBoss etc) and point it on two different HTTP Ports. So the configuration URL would look somewhat as below -

***App1*** -  - 172.2.29.155:**8080**

***App2*** -  - 172.2.29.155:**8083**